# In the DOM, what's the difference between the "Window" and "window" objects?

Tags: dom

In the DOM, we have `Window` and `window` objects. what's the difference between them? Thanks

Comment: The DOM standard does not define either of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

`Window` is a "constructor" for `window` object, which is global object.
Note that you can't really construct a new window object.

```
> window.constructor === Window
true
```

There are also "constructors" for DOM nodes and other elements.